# Azure SQL Databaseに入れたimage型のデータ型をbyte[]で取り出したい

Tags: c#, azure

SqlDataReaderでimageデータ型のbyte配列をデータ型で取り出したい。

今のところ `sqldatareader.getbytes()` を使うやり方があるみたいだけど使い方がわからない。

Answer (score 2):

`image`型は[`SqlDataReader.GetStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)で取得します。

Comment: そのstreamをどう処理すればbyte配列は取り出せますか？

Answer (score 0):

> SqlDataReaderでimageデータ型のbyte配列をデータ型で取り出したい。

Item プロパティで当該 Image 列の値を取得し、byte[] にキャストすれば取れます。

SqlDataReader.Item[] プロパティ
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item

例えば以下の Photo という image のフィールドの場合、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下の通り Item プロパティを使って値を取得し、byte[] にキャストすれば取れます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: それだとなぜかinvalidcastエラーが発生します

Comment: NULL が混じってるんじゃないですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます

Comment: また別問題で4312302バイトの長さの画像データをデータベースに格納したのに取り出したときは13バイトしかありませんでした。
何が原因なのでしょうか

Comment: そんなことは、エスパーならともかく、このスレッドに書いてあること以外知り得ない自分に、分かるはずはありません。